# Subsetting a set of data

Tags: r

I am trying to subset a set of multivariate data using the code below but I kept getting error. I need someone to help me out. the code is as thus:

```
mu<-c(2,3,4)

sigma<-matrix(c(4,2,-3,2,16,-1,-3,-1,9),byrow=TRUE,ncol=3)

library(mvtnorm)

X=rmvnorm(100,mu,sigma)

x1=X[1:n,1]

rep1 = sample(x1=1:length(x1), size = 0.1*length(x1), replace = FALSE)

x1[rep1] = max(x1) + x1[rep1]
```

the error I got is this:

```
Error in sample(x1 = 1:length(x1), size = 0.1 * length(x1), replace = FALSE) : 

unused argument (x1 = 1:length(x1))
```

Somebody should advice on what to do. Thanks

Comment: In the `sample` command, you have x1 as an argument.  You need to use `x=1:length(x1)`.  However, this is a programming specific question and is likely off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you what the problem is. You passed an argument named `x1` to `sample`, but `sample` does not take an argument called `x1`. That is an error.

Some functions allow a special argument called `...` that allows it to accept an arbitrary number of arguments with arbitrary names. `sample` [is not one of those functions](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/functions/sample). You can also type `?sample` in the R console for help, or type `args` to just print* the function "signature" (the name and arguments) to standard output.

By the way, this is purely a programming question, so it's better suited for http://stackoverflow.com than here.

*Actually, `args(sample)` technically returns a new function with the same arguments as `sample`, but no body. This means that it won't show up in a loop unless you explicitly use `print(args(sample))`.

Comment: Thanks ssdecontrol for your help. I greatly appreciate it. But Joshua a member of stack exchange has already pointed out the source of the error and the error has been corrected following the suggestion. Thanks once again

Comment: @SunnyBest ssdecontrol's more comprehensive comments have good advice beyond my quick comment.  Particularly, ?sample (or ? for any command) can be very useful in troubleshooting errors.

Comment: Thanks anyway your advice really worked. I have found the root of the error. Thanks to you cus you were the one that pointed my attention to it.@Joshua

Comment: We like to have questions answered "officially" here, even if the comments were enough to get you what you need. That's because answers are searchable and comments aren't. It also helps with monitor activity and quality on the site better. That's why we encourage people to answer their _own_ questions if they figure out the answer by themselves. That, and I also started writing this before the comment was posted.